# Parsing the xml file

Tags: ios, iphone, nsxmlparser

I want parse the xml file using NSXMLParserDelegate. The data of the xml file is below

```
<IntervalBlock xmlns="http://naesb.org/espi">
    <interval>
        <duration>86400</duration>
        <start>1330578000</start>
        <!-- start date: 3/1/2012 5:00:00 AM -->
    </interval> <IntervalReading>
    <cost>539919</cost>
    <timePeriod>
        <duration>86400</duration>
        <start>1330578000</start>
         <!-- 3/1/2012 5:00:00 AM  -->
    </timePeriod>
    <value>57751</value> </IntervalReading> </IntervalBlock> <IntervalBlock xmlns="http://naesb.org/espi">
    <interval>
        <duration>86400</duration>
        <start>1330664400</start>
        <!-- start date: 3/2/2012 5:00:00 AM -->
    </interval> <IntervalReading>
    <cost>548528</cost>
    <timePeriod>
        <duration>86400</duration>
        <start>1330664400</start>
         <!-- 3/2/2012 5:00:00 AM  -->
    </timePeriod>
    <value>58672</value> </IntervalReading> </IntervalBlock>
```

I'm using below code to parse the xml.

```
if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"start"])
    {
        NSString *tym=string;
        NSTimeInterval epoch = [tym doubleValue];
        NSDate * date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:epoch];
        [graphDate addObject:date];
    }
```

But the problem is when I'm using above code my array graphDate contains the value for start which is between interval block. I just want to add the value for start which is between timePeriod block.

Thanks

Comment: post the didStartElement delegate method of NSXMLParser

Answer (score 0):

Convert this xml string to In NSDictionary Using Library library https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary  After converting you  can easily get Value

Answer (score 0):

Just use a flag like:

Declare a flag like:

```
BOOL flag = NO;
```

And use it like:

```
if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"timePeriod"])
{
    flag = YES;
}
else if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"interval"])
{
   flag = NO;
}

if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"start"] && flag)
{
   NSString *tym=string;
   NSTimeInterval epoch = [tym doubleValue];
   NSDate * date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:epoch];
   [graphDate addObject:date];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I will give you a working example, not the whole parsing code it would be too easy. Now try to understand it and use it to your needs, not much work needed here. anyway if you have any questions feel free to ask.

```
 - (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
    {

        stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSData *xmlData = [URL dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];

        [rssParser setDelegate:self];

        [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

        //start parsing
        [rssParser parse];
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
        NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
        NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);

        UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
        //NSLog(@"found this element in didstart: %@", elementName);
        currentElement = [elementName copy];
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Interval-Block"]) {
            item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            currentDuration = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            currentStart = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
        //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"interval"]) {
            [item setObject:currentDuration forKey:@"duration"];
            [item setObject:currentStart forKey:@"start"];
                [stories addObject:[item copy]];
                NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
        }

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
        NSLog(@"found characters in found characters: %@", string);
        // saving current items here
        if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"duration"]) {
            [currentTitle appendString:string];
        } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"start"]) {
            [currentModule appendString:string];}
    }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
        //end of parsing
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

        NSLog(@"all done!");
        NSLog(@"enjoy ! :)")
        NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [stories count]);
        [newsTable reloadData];
    }


    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
```

Comment: In above code I'm getting error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: okay did you declare a currentDuration and a currentStart in you .h ?

Comment: the error is telling you that you are trying to insert nil object in the NSMutableArray. get rid of the NSLog in didEndElement, and add an exception breakpoint to your app and we will see were it gets buggy.